# Wrong sender mail address

Tags: java, email, smtp, gmail

Hi I'm trying to send email, but i constantly get wrong sender email address, it is basically the same address of the account I'm receiving mail. In code and debug looks like I'm sending address OK, but when I receive mail it comes with wrong address. I've tried with several different accounts and all had same problem. Any clue what I am missing or doing wrong?

This is my code for sending email:

```
void sendEmail(Email email) throws Exception {

    final String to = email.getEmailTo();

    final String name = email.getName();

    final String lastName = email.getLastName();

    final String from = email.getEmailFrom();

    final String password = email.getPassword();

    // Assuming you are sending email from smtp.gmail.com
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(to, password);
        }

    });

    session.setDebug(true);

    try {

        InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from, name + " "
                + lastName);

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(fromAddress);
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(email.getSubject());
        message.setText(email.getMessage() + " " + from);
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException messageException) {
        throw new RuntimeException(messageException);
    }catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
```

Debug:

```
235 2.7.0 Accepted
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<my.test.email.sender@gmail.com>
250 2.1.0 OK dj7sm7618504wjb.3 - gsmtp
RCPT TO:<my.test.email.receiver@gmail.com>
250 2.1.5 OK dj7sm7618504wjb.3 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   my.test.email.receiver@gmail.com
DATA
354  Go ahead dj7sm7618504wjb.3 - gsmtp
From: Email Sender <my.test.email.sender@gmail.com>
To: my.test.email.receiver@gmail.com
Message-ID: <1979522159.01432382909940.JavaMail.Pero@Pero-PC>
Subject: Hi
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Is it working?  my.test.email.sender@gmail.com.

250 2.0.0 OK 1432382910 dj7sm7618504wjb.3 - gsmtp
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection dj7sm7618504wjb.3 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Google's SMTP server for sending this message.

When you do that, Google's rules apply. It basically puts your Gmail account as the sender, unless you have set up the alternative address *in advance* in your Gmail account, and it's an address you own.

The reason for this is that spammers and propagators of malware use this technique of sending mail that pretends to be from somebody else, and Google does not want to become a party to this sort of activity. So they limit the `from` address to whatever is set up in advance and has been verified to belong to you.

You can see the information on how to set up alternative "from" addresses on your Gmail account [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en&ref_topic=3395757).

Another option is to use a different SMTP server that does not have this kind of limitation, but setting up an SMTP server that will be trusted by all recipient servers is not a trivial task - it's easy to get blacklisted if you don't have various verification records in your domain server etc. It's almost always best to rely on the SMTP server of some reliable service provider, but if you do that, you have to follow their rules, and they may also have similar rules regarding source address.

Comment: This answers my question, but unfortunately doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @progulj Why not? Have you tried setting up your "from" address as an alternative address at Gmail, or is your problem somewhere else?

Comment: Yes I've tried, and it works perfectly, but problem is that I don't know who will send me e-mail ,and from which domain, so I probably " use a different SMTP server that does not have this kind of limitation" go with this option. Any link for that? :D Ty btw.

Comment: I've had a lot of success with MailGun.